# Count distinct values within a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Any idea how can I count unique values within a column when values are separated with comma (when there are more than one value)?

For example:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I'm using BigQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SPLIT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) with subsequent [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) ([NULLIF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#nullif) is required for skipping empty values during counting):

```
with mytable as (
    select 1 as id, '11' as values union all
    select 2, '11,22' union all 
    select 3, '' union all
    select 4, '11,22,22,33' union all
    select 5, '44,55,66,77' union all
    select 6, '77,88,99'
)
select id, 
       (select count(distinct NULLIF(v,'')) 
        from unnest(split(values)) as v) as values
from mytable
```

[image]